# Parse Javascript SDK Query for PFObject "User" returns nil

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

As the question title describes, I've created a custom PFObject class called "User". This class works as expected with the iOS SDK, but when I try and access this class from the Javascript SDK, the query returns null.

Here is the code I use to make the query:

```
function getUserWithID() {

  Parse.initialize("...", "...");

  var userID = "someid";

  var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var query = new Parse.Query(User);
  query.equalTo("userID", userID);

  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " users.");

    },
    error: function(error) {

      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

    }
  });

}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Am I missing something or is there an issue with the SDK?

*This same snippet successfully retrieves objects of other classes.

Comment: Did you create the User class, or is the the User class that's provided by Parse?

Comment: I created my own PFObject "User" type rather than the default PFUser "User" class.

Comment: I wonder why you did that.

Comment: Rather than relying on Parse to handle login/out & manage user sessions, I wanted to write that code myself to make the transition from Parse to an in-house backend less painful in the future. Creating a "User" object was the most logical way to accomplish that.